# AND/OR operations on lists in Java

Tags: java, list, java-8

Let consider two arraylists.

```
ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list1.add(1);
list1.add(2);
list1.add(3);

ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list2.add(3);
list2.add(4);
list2.add(5);
```

I want to perform AND and OR operation between these lists. 
For example, 
here when I perform AND operation b/w list1 & list2 output should be a list containing only 3
when I perform OR operation b/w list1 & list2 output should be a list containing 1,2,3,4,5(not 3 repeating twice).

Is there any possibility in Java to achieve this scenario? Can we use Java 8 Streams in this case?
Please give me the most efficient way to get the answer.

Comment: You mean a *set intersection* and a *set union*. Try using sets.

Comment: @khelwood he asked for lists

Comment: @pivovarit That doesn't mean that using sets wouldn't be part of the solution to his problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Using the Stream API:**

```
List<Integer> union = Stream.concat(list1.stream(), list2.stream())
                            .distinct()
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

```
List<Integer> intersection = list1.stream()
                                  .filter(list2::contains)
                                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

**Without the Stream API:**

```
List<Integer> intersection = new ArrayList<>(list1);
intersection.retainAll(list2);
```

```
List<Integer> union = new ArrayList<>(list1);
List<Integer> toAdd = new ArrayList<>(list2);
toAdd.removeAll(list1);  // avoid duplicates
union.addAll(toAdd);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `Set`s to avoid duplicates. Then it's just a matter of using `addAll()`, `removeAll()` and `retainAll()` operations.

Comment: @DeepakShajan _"Give me the code"_ I think you are not aware about how SO works... Try to think by yourself a bit, this answer already gives you the solution.

Comment: @AlexisC.: I want to know how he approached the question, it can only be understood by the code.

Comment: @DeepakShajan And what prevent you from writing this code? He already gave you all the methods that you should use. With a little bit of reflexion and efforts (reading the documentation for ex.), you'd have no problem to do that. You should have a level of abstraction instead of asking the "specific" code that solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* insist on Streams, here's what you can do:

For the *AND*, you can do:

```
List<Integer> AND = list1.stream()
                         .filter(list2:contains)
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

For the *OR*, you can do:

```
List<Integer> OR =  Arrays.asList(list1, list2)
                         .stream()
                         .flatMap(List::stream)
                         .distinct()
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or even better, as suggested by [@Alexis C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1587046/alexis-c) and inspired by [@aioobe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/276052/aioobe):

```
List<Integer> OR = Stream.concat(list1.stream(), list2.stream())
                         .distinct()
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Can I add it to the answer? :)

Comment: [...] output should be *a list* containing 1,2,3,4,5(not 3 repeating twice) [...]

Comment: @aioobe, the `AND` is a list. And it contains only `3`. :)

Comment: @aioobe You can always do `.collect(collectingAndThen(toSet(), ArrayList::new)`)... if you really need a list. Or `distinct()` followed by `toList()` (better IMO) ...

Comment: @Alexis C.: `collectingAndThen(toSet(), ArrayList::new)` does not maintain the order. You may use `collectingAndThen(toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new), ArrayList::new)` instead…

Comment: @Holger Yes, I know although the OP didn't precise he wanted the resulting list as the same order. I find it weird to use lists anyway as the semantics of those operations should imply to use sets instead...

Answer (score 1):

It could be useful:

```
Set<Integer> orSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
    orSet.addAll(list);
    orSet.addAll(list1);
    List<Integer> orList = new ArrayList<Integer>(orSet);
    List<Integer> andList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int i=0;
    Iterator<Integer> itr = list.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()){
        int v = itr.next();
        if(list1.contains(v)){
            andList.add(v);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(orList);
    System.out.println(andList);
```

Comment: There is no need to use `Iterator` manually (since Java 5), just iterate using `for(Integer v: list) …`. Further, you don’t need to repeat the type of the collections: `Set<Integer> orSet = new HashSet<>();`, `List<Integer> orList = new ArrayList<>(orSet);`, etc. (since Java 7). When answering a Java 8-specific question, you should consider this. And note that `HashSet` has no ordering guarantees and might be unsuitable for `List` merging, use `LinkedHashSet` instead…